# C# Repository Pattern in Web API

Tags: c#, repository-pattern

I have a ASP.NET WEB API  project with repository and unit of work pattern architecture. My goal is simple, follow dependency injection pattern to maintain testable architecture.
I am interested in what is the best way to inject repository into respective controller;
For example: IUserRepository into UserController
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Generally speaking, UOW pattern is used with a DI container. Which container are you using?

Comment: I am using Ninject

Comment: I think you need to add more information to the question. Explain what have you tried and what is not working. There are plenty of resources online that explain how to use a DI container with WebAPI. Try narrowing down what is not working, because what is asked here is very broad.

Comment: Thanks for your attention :) i am stuck in these two options https://gist.github.com/kakha-tezela/49db5672fef19683f2e7d1dec6ddbc0f

Comment: Constructor injection is what most people use, but I would add a base class so you always have the UOW scoped generally in all subclasses.

Comment: I am using moq framework for my unit testing and i am mocking dependencies so which one is better way from listed above ?

Answer (score 0):

Here in an article that I wrote to show how you can use UnitOfWork and have testable(injecting dependencies) code.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1157241/Very-Thin-Database-Layer-using-UnitOfWork-Pattern

Hope this helps

Comment: First of all Thanks, my question is how to inject repository in a controller. for example Inject IunitOfWork or ICustomerRepository. Following your sample u are injecting IUnitOfWork . so is it right way ? unit testing in mind :)

Comment: You should never inject the Repo direct into you Controller, you should have a service that holds the business logic and write test for services, so that you can mock IUnitOfWork.
If you want to write integration tests that you do not need to mock anything just call the implementation of the Service.

Comment: aha so in my case this would be correct https://gist.github.com/kakha-tezela/86ebe0ee8e288666150ce9a11c1e9cea

Comment: "yes", but wrap you IUnitOfWork with a Factory pattern so that you do not create a DbContext soon as the Controller creates, because it may be unnecessary.

Comment: aha and in my unit testing project i would mock my IUnitOfWork. thanks for your attention and advices

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, try to only inject the APIs/ parts of your code that you need. In your example, that would mean just the repository/ repositories used by your controller, and not the entire unit of work.

As your controller grows, you may want more methods available (like saving, which may only be on your `IUnitOfWork`). In that case, you would inject the `IUnitOfWork`, or simply inject a version of `IUnitOfWork` that only has the save method (e.g. as `IDataSaver`)

This makes it easier to look after your Controller, because you can see from the constructor which areas of the application are being used by your controller (in your case, only one repository).

Comment: My application has many transaction-like logics that is implemented by unitOfWork. that hints me to inject IUnitOfWork instead of ICustomerRepository :)